# After installing rails, how to run rails server on amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I installed rails on an instance on amazon AMI. I installed all the dependencies for rails. I even copied the code through scp. When i ssh to the instance i ran

```
rails s
```

The server is running. How can I view it from the browser?
from the Public DNS???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your amazon ec2 instance has a public ip address and domain name, see
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

use this domain name as the URL in your browser.

You will also have to set inbound traffic / port connections in the security group of the instance.

A word of warning: with "rails s" you are starting webrick, a server that is only meant to be used in development.  You probably should use a production server like apache + mod_passenger.

For more advanced usage of ec2 and ruby on rails see

http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=asciicast

Comment: The solution is to change inbound port connections in the security group of the instance.

Comment: I'm still having the problem where I can't connect. I've changed my security rules to allow all traffic. Is there another setting?

Comment: just change your inbound traffic settings.

Answer (score 7):

In summary, sure that your security group have a rule for TCP 3000.Then, you can use the Public DNS:

rails server -b ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  -p 3000

And access to:  ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000

This works for me.

Comment: yes, needed to pass the internal ip address of the EC2 instance to the -b flag:
`rails server -b xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

move to folder from rails aplication and type`rails s -b 0.0.0.0`